# In WXWidget, How Call C++ Function In Javascript

Tags: javascript, c++, webview, wxwidgets

I Make WXWebview Frame,
and import html file in wxWebView file.

I call js function inside wxWebView like this

webview->RunScript("jsFunction");

However, I don't know how to call c++(wxWebview) function in js file

Comment: I think the best you can do is have a line in your script navigate to an anchor, handle the wxEVT_WEBVIEW_NAVIGATING or wxEVT_WEBVIEW_NAVIGATED event, and the call the c++ function in the handler for that event.

Comment: However can you show how can i navigate to an achor?

Comment: I really don't know much about java script, but googling the phrase "javascript navigate to anchor" should give you an example of how to do it.